# The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am making a catalog app, I have to named the items but it's not working.

```
class item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final num price;
  final String color;
  final String image;

  item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.price, this.color, this.image});
}
```

The Error:
{String id}
Type: String

The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

[Full Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1IjF.png)

Comment: Is this question for Dart or Kotlin? If Dart, I recommend reading this section of the documentation to understand the problem and the solution for that problem: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using *named* arguments, the values can be null. You have to add the `required` keyword:

```dart
class item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final num price;
  final String color;
  final String image;

  item({required this.id, required this.name, required this.desc, required this.price, required this.color, required required this.image});
}
```

Or, make the values nullable using `?`:

```dart
class item {
  final String? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? desc;
  final num? price;
  final String? color;
  final String? image;

  item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.price, this.color, this.image});
}
```

Comment: how I can make null?

Comment: @user8584321 That's what my second option shows. How you read the entire answer?

Comment: I mean where to put "?"

Comment: @user8584321 What do you mean? I have included that in my answer.

Comment: my code is working with your first code but I want to make null

Comment: oh ok sorry my bad

Comment: @user8584321 So, is the problem resolved?

Comment: yes resolved thank you.